# How to change center of UIView, added in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have added an UIButton and an UIView through Storyboard, and created their IBOutlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var popUpView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
```

When I try to change `center` or `frame`, it does not work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        popUpView.center = CGPoint(x:50,y:50)
        nexButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
    }
```

But this works:

```
nextButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.2 * nextButton.bounds.size.width
```

Comment: Why you need to change center? place that view at desired place from initial configuration!!

Comment: Are you using the Auto Layout? If yes then you have to create the outlet of the constraint which you want to change dynamically.

Comment: Try calling layoutIfNeeded() before the ending brace in viwDidAppear() method!

Answer (score 0):

I added outlet of the bottom constraint, and change it. Thanks @Bharat Modi